# Node.js set setKeepAlive not stopping a timeout with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, timeout, keep-alive

I'm trying to figure out how Node.js's net class works with timeouts and keepalives. I am setting them on the server side and watching to see what difference it makes setting these variables. I notice that if I set the keepalive to the following:

```
// Set keepalive
socket.setKeepAlive( true, 30000 );
```

It will absolutely in fact send keepalive packets which I observe with Wireshark.

[image: Keep alive with Wireshark]

However, even if I subscribe to the socket's timeout event, the socket will not timeout. So I try setting the socket's timeout option.

```
// Set timeout variables
socket.setTimeout( 60000 );
```

Even combined with the keepAlive option, the socket still times out after 60 seconds pretty much after its last real transmitted packet.

[image: Connection timeout]

So my question is, what's the point of keepAlive if it doesn't really do anything to prevent socket timeouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.setTimeout()` merely emits the `timeout` event when there has been no *data* received after whatever duration you specify. The `socket.setKeepAlive()` is for sending keepalive probes as a means for detecting dead sockets.

These two features are operating at two different "levels/layers." Keepalive probes are not considered "data," so that is why you're seeing the `timeout` event still.

Comment: What's a "dead" socket? If I pull the Ethernet wire, the socket still stays alive and doesn't emit any end/error signals. It will even let me still try and send data to it. It only sends a keep-alive once, and then doesn't emit anything further. The socket must have really died.

Comment: Dead sockets are sockets that have not replied to sent keepalive probes in x amount of time (the number of keepalive probes, the amount time, and other parameters are OS-level settings and are configurable (at least on *nix)). Often times the defaults for these mean dead sockets are not detected until hours later. This is why it's always best to use application-level keepalive messages to determine dead connections.